# Conflict of interest statement for Elsevier

Tags: publications, conflict-of-interest, patents

I want to submit a research paper to an Elsevier Journal. There is also an invention disclosure associated with this work. I have got the approval of the Technology Transfer Office to submit the paper. Do I need to report anything in the Conflict of Interest statement?

Comment: Why are you asking here rather than at Elsevier?

Comment: No response from them.

Comment: And why do you expect we would know better?

Comment: Because this should be a common enough situation that many would have already been through.

Comment: Just do a search of the other papers in the journal for "patent" and copy what they do.

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to license a patent, this might be a conflict of interest.  For example, the interest in getting accurate data might conflict with the interest in getting money from a license.

I recommend disclosure if there is any possibility someone might perceive a conflict of interest.